# I have made the custom post type but its single view is going to index

Tags: custom-post-types

Here's my code:

```
function create_posttype() {

    register_post_type( 'movies',
        // CPT Options
        array(    'public' => true,

            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'Movies' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'Movie' )
            ),
            'has_archive' => true,
            'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'movies'),
        )
    );
}

// Hooking up our function to theme setup

add_action( 'init', 'create_posttype' );
```

I have also created the `archive-movies.php` and `single-movies.php`, but when I open the detail page of a post, it's going to index.php and showing the blogs list.

Comment: Have you flushed the rewrite rules - just visit the permalink settings page?

Comment: yes i did now but no change

Comment: Does the link actually point to the single post page? How does it look like? Have you tried a default theme?

Comment: i solved by using bypass index to single-movies through post_type